# Is it appropriate to ask about Android certification providers on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

There is [this new Android Academy Certifications](http://accreditation.androidacademy.com/about), and I would like to ask about the validity/acceptance of such certifications in the development community.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* fit into https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
based on the "freelancing and business concerns" bullet in the [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), but it definitely doesn't belong on StackOverflow.

Of course, a lot depends on how you phrase your question there. You might want to ask on [Programmers Meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.

Comment: Latest ProgSE questions that fit the "validity/acceptance of such certifications in the development community" description were heavily down voted. I don't think they are good questions for Stack Exchange in general...

Comment: kind of update: **[Why do certification questions keep getting closed? (at Programmers meta)](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6443/31260)**